# Facebook: I tagged my friends in a post but it doesn't appear on their timeline

Tags: facebook

This seems like a bug to me.

I've made a post, uploaded photos and tagged 3 friends of mine into my post. The privacy of the post has been set to friends. Hovering with the mouse of the privacy icon of the post, it says it will be seen by my friends, the people tagged and the friends of the people tagged.

The post however doesn't appear on their timeline.
None of my friends tagged has enabled the "review" tag feature.
On their profile I can only see the photos on the left sidebar but the actual post doesn't appear into their timeline.

I have another post where I tagged another friend a few weeks ago, tagged in the same way and the post + photo shows up on their profile just fine.

Why this happens and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Try to clear cache of your browser or use another browser. It happens sometime.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend likely has [Activity review](https://www.facebook.com/help/247746261926036) enabled.

Activity review lets the user tagged review each post they are tagged in to determine if they wish to display it on their timeline.